# how to set AWTPermission replaceKeyboardFocusManager

Tags: java, permissions, awt, privileges

Briefly  i am developing an application, where i tried to set the permission manually in `java.policy` file but there is no effect. It generates the same exception everytime..

```java
java.lang.SecurityException: this KeyboardFocusManager is not installed in the current thread's context
    at java.awt.KeyboardFocusManager.getGlobalFocusedWindow(KeyboardFocusManager.java:733)
    at javaapplication1.Temp.go(Temp.java:26)
    at javaapplication1.Temp.main(Temp.java:35)
```

is there anyway, programtically or manually by which i can add this line,
permission java.awt.AWTPermission "replaceKeyboardFocusManager";

into the `java.Policy`, i need to get this thing working, is there something i am missing.?

Comment: `..., is there something i am missing.?`  I think that answer is yes, edit your question, post an  [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/), short, runnable, compilable, generating a.m. exception, then `.... this thing working`

Comment: public class Temp extends KeyboardFocusManager {
    
        public void go()
        {
            try
           {                       System.out.println(getGlobalFocusedWindow().getName().toString());
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    public static void main(String[] ar)
    {
        new Temp().go();
    }

Comment: ooops... sry for that here is the new link of same question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18526880/trying-to-set-awtpermission-replacekeyboardfocusmanager-but-security-exception